# Create a JSON dict from a list of values from a tuple and a separate list of keys

Tags: python, json

I have a list of tuple and want to make JSON from it

```
[(1, 'a', 'A'), (2, 'b', 'B'), (3, 'c', 'C'), (4, 'd', 'D'), (5, 'e', 'E'), (6, 'f', 'F'), (7, 'g', 'G'), (8, 'h', 'H'), (9, 'i', 'I')]
```

And Expected JSON

```
{
    "List": [
                {
                    "name": "1",
                    "description": "a",
                    "type": "A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "2",
                    "description": "b",
                    "type": "B"
                },
                {
                    "name": "3",
                    "description": "c",
                    "type": "C"
                },
               and so on....
            ]
}
```

How can i do that?

The duplicate identified answers didn't work and gave this error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [more pythonic way to format a JSON string from a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761054/more-pythonic-way-to-format-a-json-string-from-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: that didn't work, gave error ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Comment: He probably only read your title, which certainly sounds like you want to do exactly what's in the nominated duplicate.  I'll edit your title for you.

Comment: @tripleee: with actions comes responsibility, if he is active enough to mark it duplicate then he must also do required research on it as well, because as people see DUPLICATE in SO, they start giving negative votes

Comment: I'm afraid the burden of creating a useful title when posting a question is on you.  Please understand that removing noise to keep the signal tolerable on this site is a major effort, handled largely by unpaid volunteers.  But individual mistakes are usually harmless, especially if you can correct any misunderstandings quickly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that. Anyways thanks for your mature words and title.
I would keep that thing in my mind for future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` the keys and each *tuple* calling dict on the result then *json.dumps*:

```
import json
keys = ["name", "description","type"]

l=[(1, 'a', 'A'), (2, 'b', 'B'), (3, 'c', 'C'), (4, 'd', 'D'), (5, 'e', 'E'), (6, 'f', 'F'), (7, 'g', 'G'), (8, 'h', 'H'), (9, 'i', 'I')]


js =  json.dumps({"List":[dict(zip(keys, tup)) for tup in l]})
```

Which gives you:

```
'{"List": [{"type": "A", "name": 1, "description": "a"}, {"type": "B", "name": 2, "description": "b"}, {"type": "C", "name": 3, "description": "c"}, {"type": "D", "name": 4, "description": "d"}, {"type": "E", "name": 5, "description": "e"}, {"type": "F", "name": 6, "description": "f"}, {"type": "G", "name": 7, "description": "g"}, {"type": "H", "name": 8, "description": "h"}, {"type": "I", "name": 9, "description": "i"}]}'
```

Comment: thanks very much but i think OrderedDict would be better for me. anyways thanks again