# Python remove characters from a list of tuple and convert to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I have this tuple:

```
(('Samsung J1',), ('Cloudfone Thrill Boost',))
```

I want to convert it to a string so it will look like this:

```
Samsung J1
Cloudfone Thrill Boost
```

I tried doing:

```
''.join(variablenamefortuple)
```

and it did not work just then I realized that it is a list of tuples so I tried mykhal's answer here: [Python - convert list of tuples to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292643/python-convert-list-of-tuples-to-string)

But the strip function only removes from the ends so the output will be like this:

```
'Samsung J1',), ('Cloudfone Thrill Boost',
```

How do I remove the extra parentheses as well as the commas and quotation marks? Thanks:)

Comment: `print('\n'.join([k[0] for k in s]))`

Comment: oh ok thanks man:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this (a small variation on @RafaelC comment):

```
s = (('Samsung J1',), ('Cloudfone Thrill Boost',))
print('\n'.join([k for k, in s]))
```

**Output**

```
Samsung J1
Cloudfone Thrill Boost
```