# Converting the content of each tuplet of a list to a string, without the parenthesis or the commas

Tags: python

I needed to make permutations of the input asked so I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools

variable1 = raw_input("input 4-6 carac")
var1list = list(variable1)
lenlist = len(var1list)
itertools.permutations(variable1)
iterlist = list(itertools.permutations(variable1, lenlist))
print iterlist
```

So I end up with a list of tuplets
So for 123 I get (1,2,3),(1,3,2)...
The problem is then I need to append each of the tuplets a string, so I can't  append a tupplet to a string. I need to convert each tuplet of the list to a string but without () or the commas.

E.g., from the list that contains the permutations of 123:

> (1,2,3),(1,3,2)...

I need to get a list that contains each of the members of each tuplet together and separated from the mebers of the other tuplets of the list:
**I'm clarifying i only want THIS one:**

> [123, 132...] or ['123', '132'...]

**These two ones are similar examples I found on already answered posts, just to clarify that I wanted something different to them**.

A literal string of tuplets

> "(1,2,3), (1,3,2)..."

Like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292643/python-convert-list-of-tuples-to-string)

or a list with all the tuplets formatted into one single list together

> [1,2,3,1,3,2...]

Like in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269161/in-python-how-to-join-a-list-of-tuples-into-one-list)

Any tip for this? I kinda control Python but I've got about none knowledge of how tuplets work.

EDIT: I think the list should be of strings (instead of integers)

Comment: Made an edit to clarify what i want, sorry if It wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case where you want this style of output:

> [123, 132...]

Try the following:

```
b = [''.join(map(str,i)) for i in a]
# ['123', '132']
```

Where `a` is your list of permutations. It `joins` the tuples as strings and creates a list of the results.

For the case where you want your output in this style:

> [1,2,3,1,3,2...]

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array(a)
b = map(str, b.reshape(-1).tolist())
# ['1', '2', '3', '1', '3', '2']
```

This uses numpy array functions to flatten your entries nicely.

Comment: The output of the first command was exactly what I wanted. Sorry if I confused any of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build a string with an appropriate delimiter from your tuples:

```
perms = [(1,2,3), (1,3,2)]
string_perms = [''.join([str(i) for i in t]) for t in perms]
print(string_perms)
# ['123', '132']
```

Comment: PO wants a list of `int` I think,  you should `map(int, string_perms)`

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ where did you get that from?

Comment: I think its input as "123" originally also so you probably dont need the cast to str

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [(1,2,3),(1,3,2)]
b = [''.join(map(str, s)) for s in a]

print (b)
# ['123', '132']
```